# Why does my DMARC report from Google have "<dkim>fail</dkim>" when all auth_results have "pass"

Tags: dkim, dmarc

We're using Microsoft 365 (outlook.office.com) for our company emails and have had DKIM set up for a while, but recently added a DMARC record. I now got a DMARC report from Google where every record has `<dkim>fail</dkim>` while all `auth_results` in it have "pass", like this:

```
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>2a01:111:f403:260d::601</source_ip> <!-- mail-db5eur01on0601.outbound.protection.outlook.com.
 -->
      <count>2</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>fail</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>COMPANYDOMAIN.com</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>SENDERDOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>selector2-SENDERDOMAIN-onmicrosoft-com</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>COMPANYDOMAIN.com</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
```

What does this mean? How do I troubleshoot why DKIM validation fails here?

When I test it by sending to dkimvalidator.com it reports "result = pass" for DKIM (and for SPF).

Answer (score 3):

1. You're not using outlook.com for your email. You're using Microsoft 365.
2. You need to create a DKIM record for your verified domain. You can enable DKIM for your verified domain in the Microsoft 365 Security Admin center>Email & collaboration>Policies & rules>Threat policies>Email authentication settings.
3. Once you enable DKIM for your verified domain you'll need to create CNAME records in your DNS based on the info generated in the Security Admin center>Email & collaboration>Policies & rules>Threat policies>Email authentication settings

Comment: Thanks. It's set up now and the DMARC reports are a mixture of pass and fail. Mostly pass, but sometimes fail - sometimes for the same sender IP! Any idea how to troubleshoot that, given that the DMARC reports give no details? (The same happens for SPF, by the way, but not "in sync" with DKIM - usually one passes while the other fails.)

Comment: Try this free tool to analyze your reports - https://us.dmarcian.com/xml-to-human-converter/?_ga=2.68454231.732522890.1651697392-171961328.1651439979

Answer (score 1):

The mail in question fails DKIM, because it does not have any vlid DKIM signature that is hosted on the domain `COMPANYDOMAIN.com`. Since you are sending it from `COMPANYDOMAIN.com`, you need to have a DKIM record that is under `COMPANYDOMAIN.com` (it can be a cname to an external domain)

The requirement for the domain of the dkim to match the from, is so an spammer can not just specify their own domain name, which they fully control and thus can make dkim always pass.

You message is passing under DMARC as SPF-Only, for the message to pass, you either need a valid DKIM or a valid SPF check

Comment: You might improve your answer by pointing to a website which explains how to add DKIM signing for a custom domain in Exchange Online: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/email-authentication-dkim-configure?view=o365-worldwide